# Mi programa en FreePascal se cierra al asignarle datos

Tags: freepascal

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al ejecutarlo como .exe y escribirle 2 numeros Ejemplo: 2 y 4, el programa se cierra automaticamente. Agradeceria su ayuda para saber el porque de esto.

Comment: Por favor, incluye los datos relevantes ([mcve], mensajes de error) **como texto**. Deberías pasarte por [El Centro de Ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) para ver como funciona el sitio. En concreto, revisa [¿Como elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Un saludo.

Comment: Por favor, no publiques imagenes de código, publica el código como tal.